# Magento 2 : how can i add notice below state/province field in shipping address in checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, shipping-address, onestepcheckout

how can i add notice or lable in checkout page below the state field just like notice below the email address in blow image,

state input element is created by region_id field in vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\layout\checkout_index_index.xml

```
<item name="customEntry" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.region</item>
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1.Create a di.xml under 'etc' directory of your any custom module

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="rewrite-checkout-fields" type="Namespace\Module\Model\Checkout\LayoutProcessorPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

2.Create a file called LayoutProcessorPlugin.php file under 'Namespace/Module/Model/Checkout'.

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Model\Checkout;

class LayoutProcessorPlugin
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */

    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['firstname']['notice'] = __('Please enter first name here'); 
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['lastname']['notice'] = __('Please enter last name here'); 
        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Note: here i add comment below first and last name you can do for others too.Please accept and vote if use full to you this will help others too.[image]

Comment: Please vote as well if acceptable will help to others.

Comment: Thankyou it work for me, but it is not working with state/province field and i need this for that field only

Comment: I checked just now it is coming also on state/provice use this: 

$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['region_id']['notice'] = __('Please choose Province');

Comment: actually in my case it is coming dynamically where State is Required

Comment: ok but it should work for all because it takes name element from field and add notice on that below the particular field.

Comment: satting is define from Stores>Configuration>General>State Options

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82412/discussion-between-hiren-and-charul-tyagi).

Comment: when you inspect your state/province field then what is there in name element?

Comment: "region", i try with region also but still it not working

Comment: can i add that notice in dynamically genrated state field ??

Comment: as you said your name element for state/province is "region" so this is not generated by default magento or you created by your custom code?

Comment: it is genrated by default for australia as i set satting in Stores>Configuration>General>State Options for australia only

Comment: i want to know here you country can be changed or will be set only Australia?

Comment: it can be change

Comment: issue is that 'region' field is not coming from ['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['region']

Comment: hi, the region field is genrated by <item name="customEntry" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.region</item> under 'region_id' in vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\layout\checkout_index_index.xml

Comment: @CharulTyagi do you know how I can add HTML in notice? I tried adding but it is showing as plain text on front-end. Any help please?

Comment: @CharulTyagi I have asked my exact question here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/301963/how-to-add-html-content-in-notice-for-checkout-form-fields-in-magento-2 please help if you can, thanks!