# Add notice under State input filed in one page checkout in magento2

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

How can i add notice under state input filed on one page checkou in magento2?

Comment: Please check this link may be helpful for you [click here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/240011/magento-2-how-can-i-add-custom-label-below-input-field-in-shipping-address-in/240048#240048)

Comment: And for state/province field i display  it below the field but more than one state fields were showing because when you will go into checkout_index_index.xml there region and region_id given i make visible false to true the "region" but two fields showing notice was coming in one of the field with not required then for doing this whole need to work on JS or css to make it customization that it should show only one field not two.

Comment: @CharulTyagi Excatly same issue facing here

Comment: I debug alot i did it and display but issue is only two fields showing at a time and when we choose United States (country) then it show state as drop down and along with input-field in which we added notice below there.

Comment: yes excatly @CharulTyagi

Comment: I think here we have to do some JS on any phtml file or js that when there is dropdown coming by choosing country then input-field should be hide and when there is no drop down then we need to hide that input-field that is extra that is without notice.

Comment: If you find any solution of above problem please post here your answer.Thanks.

Comment: @CharulTyagi sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried like below:

In **app\design\frontend\wenro\wenro15\Magento_Checkout\web\js\model\address-converter.js**

in address-converter.js file in **formAddressDataToQuoteAddress** function

```
           var i=0;
           if(!$('div[name="shippingAddress.region"]').children().hasClass('field-note') && i==0)
            {
                setTimeout(function(){ $('div[name="shippingAddress.region"]').append("<div class='field-note'><span>Enter state in full eg. South Australia not SA</span></div>"); }, 1600);

               i++;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

for add notice in checkout you need to follow the Magecomp Blog. here is the link.

https://magecomp.com/blog/add-custom-comment-magento-2-checkout-shipping-address-fields/

Comment: This solution i have already tried!! and it's works for all other fields excepting state filed.