# Magento 2.3.2 : how can i add notice below street field in shipping address on checkout page

Tags: magento2.3, shipping-address, checkout-page

In our case, we will always have two input fields for street address. I want to add notice below the 2nd input field of street. I have override layoutProcess file and just like given in below link, it is adding notice to every input field except street.

[Magento 2 : how can i add notice below state/province field in shipping address in checkout page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/240011/magento-2-how-can-i-add-notice-below-state-province-field-in-shipping-address?newreg=3a9e0554354b47ad832b6aac94548306)

[image]

**I have tried following so far:**

```
$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
            ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street[1]']
            ['notice'] = __('This is my custom notice.');


$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
            ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street']
            ['notice'] = __('This is my custom notice.');

$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
            ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street.1']
            ['notice'] = __('This is my custom notice.');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This :-**

```
$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
            ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street']['children'][1]
            ['notice'] = __('This is my custom notice.');
```

Comment: Thanx..it worked for me. :)